# Why TREC set two task: document ranking and passage ranking

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, information-retrieval

TREC is https://microsoft.github.io/TREC-2019-Deep-Learning/

I am new to text retrieval. Still can not understand why set the two similar task.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the two tasks is to explore how document length affects the effectiveness of the different retrieval models.

Ellen Voorhees
TREC project manager 
NIST